# Border с помощью ::after и ::before

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую обводку?

Я сделал `border-bottom,left,right`. А как сделать верхнюю часть и текст не понимаю. Знаю, что `::before` и `::after`, но все равно что-то не получается.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте `fieldset` + `legend`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

input {
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
}

legend {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

form {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, ответ @HamSter оптимальный, и в вёрстке форм правильно использовать именно такой вариант. Но если Вам понадобится аналогичным образом стилизовать просто какие-нибудь дивы (а не формы), то псевдоэлементы вполне для этого годятся:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
form {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 30px 10px 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 290px;
  position: relative;
}
form:after,
form:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
form:before {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  left: -2px;
}
form:after {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  right: -2px;
}
span {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 90px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input {
  width: 240px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>Заголовок формы:</span>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Только вот текст уехал https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8MvH.png

Comment: @andreymal, не знаю - у меня всё нормально отображается. видимо, Вы не в хроме смотрите )) но это ведь всего лишь вопрос подгонки размера - можно сделать кроссбраузерно и даже адаптивно